# "Login" button doesn't respond to clicks

Tags: html, facebook, authentication, joomla, click

I'm building a Joomla website ([here](https://tuqmobile.com/tuqmobile), still under construction) and I'm adding in facebook support.  I've downloaded and installed the Joomla [Facebook SDK](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/facebook-integration/12792), and now I'm trying to add login and registration with Facebook.

I made a Custom HTML module in the top-a position, and dropped in the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=MY_APP_ID&amp;xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<fb:login-button registration-url="https://REGISTRATION_URL"></fb:login-button>​
```

where the registration url points to a page with the registration button on it (is that right?)

The Login button appears with the word "Login" but does not respond to clicks.  The Chrome console doesn't register any errors, and neither does Firebug.

This may be a very simple problem since I'm relatively new to this kind of coding, and not very comfortable with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla filters content by default and removes Javascript. Use [plugins like these](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content) to allow you to enter custom code [JS, PHP etc...], and [these for FB login](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/facebook-integration)